# Pcap4J: Unable to load library 'pcap'

Tags: java, linux, pcap, libpcap, pcap4j

I run an application uses Pcap4J on Windows 10. It worked correct (with Admin privileges).

When I run the same application on Linux (Cent OS 7) I got this error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'pcap': Native
>   library (linux-x86-64/libpcap.so) not found in resource path
>   ([file:/tmp/spark-e5c4a3c6-8ee1-4b60-9fc0-941cdc83f521/userFiles-3b9fc272-3010-4467-83cb-50378b87e4aa/my_app.jar])

I tried:

1. Install libcap: `yum install libcap-devel`
2. Run with root privileges
3. Search `libpcap.so` file:

   - in [libpcap-1.8.1.tar.gz](http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.8.1.tar.gz), [tcpdump-4.9.0.tar.gz](http://www.tcpdump.org/release/tcpdump-4.9.0.tar.gz) and [Pcap4J repo](https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j)
   - in Linux: `find / -name libpcap.so`
   - for download in google
   - in jars in .m2 and .ivy2 caches

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

Instead of developer package (libcap-devel) I should install usual package:

```
yum install libpcap.x86_64
```

The name of the package may be different. You can list all avaliable packages by command:

```
 yum list available | grep libpcap
```